# No faces or hands vs no faces and hands vs no faces and no hands

Tags: negation

> 1. Electric clocks have no faces and hands.
> 2. Electric clocks have no faces or hands.
> 3. Electric clocks have no faces and no hands.

Which is suitable?

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt, use (2). I'll quickly go through what each of them means, though.

Also, note that what you're describing are called *digital* clocks. Pretty much every clock, whether analog (face and hands) or digital (just numbers displayed) is electric, in that it uses electricity.

In order of how common these are:

---

> 2. Digital clocks have no faces or hands.

This is the normal wording, neutral in style and suitable for every register and context.

As a side note, a more formal wording that takes advantage of this formula would be this:

> Digital clocks have **neither** faces **nor** hands.

But this isn't something most siblings would say to each other. They would probably say (2).

---

> 3. Digital clocks have no faces and no hands.

This is almost as common as (2). It means the same thing, but this particular wording is in a less neutral style. It emphasizes the absence of both the elements.

> You might think that all clocks have faces and hands, but digital clocks have *no* faces and *no* hands. Imagine that!

---

> 1. Digital clocks have no faces **and** hands.

This is an unlikely sentence, and it's even a little difficult to interpret. Making sense of this requires treating "faces and hands" as a single unit, maybe if someone already mentioned it earlier.

> — "What do you mean, how do clocks display time? All clocks have faces and hands. The hands just move around on the face."
>   
> — "Yeah, but we have a digital clock. Digital clocks *have* no 'faces and hands'. What I mean is, how does the digital display work?"

The context would have to be quite colloquial for this to work.